# Where can I place the word “jetzt” in a sentence

Tags: grammar, word-order

I have been learning German for only a few weeks and one of my frequent mistakes is with the word *jetzt*.
I know it is possible to use it at the beginning of a sentence but I wonder if there is a rule about using it in the middle of the sentence and when it is possible to use on the end of the sentence.

Comment: Learning Portuguese is hard already...I try to imagine German :D

Answer (score 4):

Very often you can use is as a translation for "now" but to find the correct position is really hard. I don't know a rule for it but I can tell you some examples.

> Es *gefällt* mir jetzt.

("I *like* it now." - emphasis on the fact that you like it)

> Jetzt gefällt es mir.

("*Now* I like it." - emphasis on the time you started to like it)

There is also a method to use it for supporting a statement.

> Das hätte ich nicht erwartet.
>   (Wow,) das hätte ich jetzt nicht erwartet.

(it kind of gives the sentence more power by showing you are really surprised at the exact momen - "Wow, I didn't see this coming!")

> Ich bin mir jetzt nicht sicher.
>   Jetzt bin ich mir nicht sicher.

(these two should mean exactly the same, something like: "I'm not really sure right now" or "Now, I'm not really sure.")

> Du sollst es *jetzt* erledigen.
>   Du sollst es erledigen.

("You are to do it *now*" - as in a command/order)

I will add some more as soon as they come to my mind :)

Answer (score 1):

`jetzt` is an adverb and such can work as an adverbial on its own.

**Purely grammatical answer**
The general word order in a German main clause is totally arbitrary except for the predicate (verbs):

- The conjugated part of the predicate is in second position.
- The other parts of the predicate (if existing) are in last position.

So, in general you can put `jetzt` in any position except those above.

**Idiomatic answer**

If you want to emphasize time, you should put `jetzt` in first place.

Otherwise you should put it after the conjugated verb. The positions between conjugated verb and other parts of the predicate are idiomatically filled in the order Time-Matter-Place, so `jetzt` should usually come first after the conjugated verb.